# How can I create a dictionary item from xml?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a generic method that will read an xml and return the node name and attribute value as a dictionary item .

I have been playing around with the syntax but can't seem to quite get it right.
What am I missing here?

Currently I have:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(dataStream);
var item = from el in doc.Descendants()
           where el.Attribute(attributeName) != null
           select new
           {
               Name = el.Name.LocalName,
               Value = el.Attribute(attributeName).Value
           }.ToDictionary(o => o.Name, o => o.Value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your LINQ query by brackets:

```
public void Test()
{
    const string attributeName = "name";
    XElement doc = XElement.Parse(@"<xml><elem id=""1"" /><anotherElem name=""test"" /></xml>");
    var items = (from el in doc.Descendants()
        where el.Attribute(attributeName) != null
        select new
        {
            Name = el.Name.LocalName,
            Value = el.Attribute(attributeName).Value
        }).ToDictionary(o => o.Name, o => o.Value);

    Assert.AreEqual(1, items.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, items.ContainsKey("anotherElem"));
    Assert.AreEqual("test", items["anotherElem"]);
}
```

Comment: I was just going to post my answer.  I didn't realize that I forgot to wrap the query.